# Array length with direct insert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var items = new Array();
```

when I try to do something like:

```
items[100] = ...
```

where `100` is an id. If then I go to print the length of the array I understand that it is big `100`. Is there a way to do such a thing, but having the length to those items?

For example, if I have:

```
var items = new Array();
items[100] = item100;
items[120] = item120;
items[150] = item150;
```

I would like the length of the array is `3` and not `150`.

Comment: Maybe an object will suit you better then if you care about the key itself?

Comment: Yes, I'd use an object. Sparse arrays are trouble.

Comment: @OmriAharon Unfortunately, due to problems, I can't use objects

Comment: Can you explain why? This looks like an XY problem, as it seems you are trying to solve it using the wrong data structure...

Comment: Weird.. then maybe place an object in the array ? :)

Comment: Should back up one level and explain what you would use this for and why it must be array. What you are asking for is not practical

Comment: It looks like you want the syntax similar to C and C++ : int foo [5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }

Comment: Does it have to be an array? What about an array-like object?

Answer (score 2):

With some small manipulation you can get the real size of array

```
items.filter(Object).length;
```

But as @charlietfl said:

> it seems you are trying to solve it using the wrong data structure...

Comment: this will fail quickly if any of the array elements contain other arrays or text with comma or spaces

Comment: @charlietfl of course, it's for numbers, just experimenting

Comment: interesting... never would have thought of this one. Also doesn't seem intuitive that it would work +1 for effort